# How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time?

Tags: boot, grub2, menu

My system is **not** dual-boot, I run a standard Ubuntu desktop system "on the metal" (I think running it in a VM is the same).

Pressing <kbd>c</kbd> while booting does not cause the GRUB menu to appear (which I believe it does for a dual-boot system).

How can I get the GRUB-menu to present itself on a **single**-boot system?

Comment: +1 excellent question to expose an essentially undocumented feature of Ubuntu boot process, the answer to which I only found by accident while groveling through grub.cfg. Thanks for hoisting this up to the top (Googleable) level.

Comment: Credit where credit is due... This issue came up in another question of mine (buried deep in the comments). Jorge Castro suggested that it would be a good idea to present as a question it its own right...  (so credit to him.... and I'm happy to bask in the reflected glow ;)   I can see the value of it being a primary Q/A.

Answer (score 433, accepted):

Menu will appear if you press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> during loading Grub, if you boot using BIOS. When your system boots using UEFI, press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

For permanent change you'll need to edit your `/etc/default/grub` file:

Place a `#` symbol at the start of line `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` to comment it out. If that line doesn't exist, then you can comment out this line instead: `# GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden`, and then change `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=5`, for instance, to give the grub menu a 5 second timeout before it automatically logs you in.

Save changes and run `sudo update-grub` to apply changes.

Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Comment: @codeMonk: Oops! (I've deleted my previous comment because I was on the wrong track)... I originally misunderstood the context of "GRUB_TIMEOUT=0". The context you mean is in relation to the **"permanent"** display of GRUB-menu... I thought you meant in relation to the **"Shift"** key method...  It is true that for a *permanently recurring* display, you need **both** "#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0" and "GRUB_TIMEOUT=*NON-ZERO*", as described in the [link in the answer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) ... (I've just test it both ways.)

Comment: It's only the *left* shift-key that works.  At first I couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong--how hard can it be to hold the Shift key?  Finally, I read carefully the link you provide and realized that it specifically says the left shirt key.

Comment: Holding left shift didn't work for me :(

Comment: Can somebody fix this answer? To my experience, the comments, and the answer below, it is obsolete and now a lot of it is just wrong (like the timeout advice).

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04 there is no `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` line in my `/etc/default/grub` - instead there is `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden` (Shift during boot never worked for me (Dell?)). Any idea what to do?

Comment: @jena I found the advice at the top of `/etc/default/grub` helpful: i.e., to have a look at `info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'`. This explains the options. Use `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu` to have the menu shown. Or press `ESC` if you keep the setting at `hidden` but want to see the menu.

Comment: @bovender Thanks, I figured it out later and forgot to write it here. Anyway, Esc still doesn't work for me, but I just set a short time (3s) for the menu, so if I need it I can use it and if not, it's not a big deal (the default 10s is too long).

Comment: Grub changes with each release, please consider adding version informatoin. The fact for example that this works only for 14.04. It sure is not relevant anymore for 18.04

Comment: On 20.04 holding the right shift key did not work but holding both down did!  YMMV :).   The official docs don't mention which key you should hold down :(

Comment: Holding the Esc key on a UEFI system with Ubuntu 18.04 takes me to the `grub>` prompt. How to get to the grub menu where you can select different kernel?

Comment: I can no longer edit my comment. Found that pressing **F1** brings the Grub menu on a Dell laptop with UEFI boot.

Comment: When pressing ESC while in the grub menu it returns to the previous menu which is the command line at first. Since you where opening the grub menu with ESC by holding the key, it took you to the menu and then directly to the command line. You can open the menu on startup by pressing ESC every 1-2 seconds instead, making sure to not press it again once the menu is shown (may take a few tries). Apparently there is a way to get back to the menu from the command-line using [normal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/381613/how-to-return-from-grub-prompt-to-the-grub-menu) but I didn't try that myself.

Comment: None of these suggestions seem to work on ubuntu server 22

Answer (score 100):

I have tried both the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd> keys but nothing works. Only the <kbd>**Esc**</kbd> key works for Ubuntu 14.04  and 16.04 to get Grub Menu at boot time.

Comment: same here. Only ESCAPE key worked with Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: The same for Ubuntu 16.04 - only Escape works. This should be mentioned in documentation (Recovery Mode)

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 here. NOTHING works.

Comment: Shift key works fine on my v16.04 .

Comment: On Xubuntu 17.10, (left) Shift did not work but ESC did.

Comment: I had to repeatedly press the ESC key, not hold it down. Let's have 6 ways to do the same thing. Linux is fun.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04: the `Esc` was the only option that worked for me.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman I suspect this is inconsistency on the side of HW manufacturers, not linux (but it's just my speculation, i didn't google it yet)

Comment: @jena Agree. I have several Ubuntu, but only one installed on Intel NUC wants `Esc` key for GRUB menu. This is problematic because if I press `Esc` too many times, it goes directly to [GRUB CLI](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Command_002dline-interface.html).

Comment: @atmelino This is an old discussion, but the esc key works only if you use UEFI to boot Ubuntu (I am sure). And the Shift Key only works with BIOS boot. No more confusion about this. Now, Ubuntu have also specified the options here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode.

Comment: @FranklinYu you are right, thats also a problem about the esc key xD

Comment: Maybe specific to Ubuntu and derivatives, but... grub2 menu should come up if the *RIGHT~HAND* Shift key is pressed while BIOS is running.  Likely, the shift key at the left of keyboard will not work.  Don't even ask.

Answer (score 41):

In Ubuntu 18.04, there is no `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` line in `/etc/default/grub` - instead there is `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden`.  According to `info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'` :

> if this option is unset or set to 'menu', then GRUB will display the menu and then   wait for the timeout set by 'GRUB_TIMEOUT' to expire before booting the default entry.  Pressing a key interrupts the timeout.

So if you either remove or comment out the line as:

```
#GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
```

and run `sudo update-grub`, then the menu will show by default.

18.04 + Not dual boot, boots in grub 5 seconds:

> GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=false
>
> GRUB_TIMEOUT=     (no value). Works fine LVM.

Comment: Perfect! Tested with this QEMU setup: https://askubuntu.com/questions/924913/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time-using-serial-console/1110209#1110209

Comment: also works in 18.10

Comment: This worked on my Late 2010 MBP with Lubuntu 19.04.

Comment: Do I need to run `sudo update-grub` after modifying this?

Comment: yes run update-grub. should be in answer

Comment: @qwr I added `sudo update-grub` to the answer.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04, I also had to provide a value for `GRUB_TIMEOUT` (above zero, logically).

Answer (score 20):

- Keep hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd> until you see "Grub Loading Message"
- After the message, hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> down until the menu appears.

Comment: This is the nuance that helped me finally get in! Thank you! :)

Comment: That so does not work for me. No matter what I do to this poor SHIFT key, this Intel NUC skips the grub menu :(

Comment: @yPhil Intel NUC is the freak who eats `Shift`. It works everywhere else. I'm lucky that `Esc` works for my NUC, but it didn't seem to work for you, did it?

Answer (score 16):

[By default](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Boot_Display_Behavior), GRUB will show the menu if there is a second operating system installed.  If only Ubuntu is installed, then GRUB will generally load Ubuntu without showing the menu.  To [reconfigure GRUB to always show a menu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Specific_Entries):

1. Edit `/etc/default/grub`:

   Set `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=` (no value after the `=` sign).
   Set `GRUB_TIMEOUT=n` to show the menu for *n* seconds.
2. Run `update-grub` to regenerate `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` based on the `/etc/default/grub` settings.

---

[You can get GRUB to show the menu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) even if the default `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` setting is in effect:

- If your computer uses BIOS for booting, then hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while GRUB is loading to get the boot menu.
- If your computer uses UEFI for booting, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> several times while GRUB is loading to get the boot menu.

Hopefully this clears up confusion as to why [<kbd>Shift</kbd> works for some users](/a/16049/165556) and [<kbd>Esc</kbd> works for others](/a/707308/165556).

Answer (score 10):

Edit `/etc/default/grub` (`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`)...

change:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
```

to:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
```

then save the file and quit the editor. Next run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

---

**GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE**

If this option is unset or set to `menu`, then GRUB will display the menu and then wait for the timeout set by `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to expire before booting the default entry. Pressing a key interrupts the timeout.

If this option is set to `countdown` or `hidden`, then, before displaying the menu, GRUB will wait for the timeout set by `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to expire. If <kbd>ESC</kbd> is pressed during that time, it will display the menu and wait for input. If a hotkey associated with a menu entry is pressed, it will boot the associated menu entry immediately. If the timeout expires before either of these happens, it will boot the default entry. In the `countdown` case, it will show a one-line indication of the remaining time.

Answer (score 8):

For newer Ubuntu versions there is no `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` instead there is `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE` which is set to `hidden` by default.

Open the file `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
Change value of `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE` from `hidden` to `menu` and make sure `GRUB_TIMEOUT` is not set to `0` then run

`sudo update-grub`

<kbd>Done!!!</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

I've heard Shift does it.
But I've used Space before and it worked.

Comment: I've just now tried both Shift and Space, in two situations: In a VM, and "on the metal" ... The "Shift" worked in both situations...  The "Space" failed in both situations...

Comment: If you can't use shift, try escape. Seems to work for me with Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04. Space key works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

##### Simple answer:

In the file **`/etc/default/grub`**, set **`GRUB_TIMEOUT=1`**, not `0`. (Or set it to some other positive number, which is interpreted as seconds.) Then run **`sudo update-grub`** after saving the edit.

##### Terminal one-liner to do this:

```
sudo sed -i 's/^.*GRUB_TIMEOUT=.*$/GRUB_TIMEOUT=1/' /etc/default/grub && sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score -1):

For me, I found the issue was that I had left a USB stick plugged in to the computer. I suppose the computer was attempting to boot from the USB stick.

**Once I had removed the USB stick**, I could press <kbd>shift</kbd> or <kbd>esc</kbd> or <kbd>space</kbd> (depending on the version of Ubuntu you are using, I think).